# WP multinetwork : cannot create subdirectory websites of secondary networks

Tags: wordpress, subdirectory, multisite

I have a wordpress multisite, with multi-network enabled (using WP multi-networks plugin). 
When I create a website (subdirectory style) within the primary network, everything works fine but when I create it in another network I get a 404 page (actually it is redirected to the default website of this network, as if it is seen as a permalink)

to be concrete :
`http://chezdom.net` => my primary network
`http://chezdom.net/test` => ok
`http://chezdom.net/voyages` => ok

`http://aaate.net` => another network, works well
`http://aaate.net/test` => redirected to `http://aaate.net`, with error 404
`http://aaate.net/2019` => redirected to `http://aaate.net`, with error 404

Any ideas?

EDIT (to answer to  Cukic0d's comment)
above I put the actual URLs so you can see the errors, then :

my `.htaccess` :
    `RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
    RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]`

and part of the `wp-config.php`
`define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);`
`define('MULTISITE', true);`
`define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);`
`/*define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'chezdom.net');*/`
`define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );`

`define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');`
`/*define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);*/`
`/*define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);*/`

`define( 'WP_HOME',    'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );`
`define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );`

`define( 'SUNRISE', 'on' );`

Comment: Hi ! Could you share pieces of your configuration, extra 404 error informations or anything that would make your problem easier to understand ? It will attract more users to help you resolve your issue !

Comment: I updated the question with all details. thanks